# How do I get the most recent value from a table in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I have a table that looks something like the following:

| loc | temp | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 22.4 | 2021-03-03T16:51:56.915000Z |
| xyz | 21.4 | 2021-03-03T16:51:56.915000Z |
| abc | 22.4 | 2021-03-03T17:05:38.238413Z |
| abc | 21.4 | 2021-03-03T17:05:38.238478Z |

What query do I need to get the most recent record back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two simple ways of getting the most recent values here, firstly, you can limit to the most recent row:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT -1;
```

But what might be more useful in this case is to use `LATEST BY`:

```sql
SELECT * from my_table LATEST BY loc;
```

This would return the most recent rows per unique value in the `loc` column:

| loc | temp | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 21.4 | 2021-03-03T16:51:56.915000Z |
| abc | 21.4 | 2021-03-03T17:05:38.238478Z |

**Edit:** More information, along with examples can be found on the [LATEST BY documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/latest-by)